# Libreria AgendaCalendarView

Tags: android

estoy usando la librería ya mencionada lo que pasa es que quiero traer el id del evento que se selecciona, para eso tiene su procedimiento

```
@Override
    public void onEventSelected(CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
}
```

Eso devuelve "titulo" y "fecha", pero no puedo hacer regresar el id del evento, y como asignarlo.

Comment: La clase AgendaCalendarView es parte del Android SDK?, si no es así agrega más información y código. Saludos.

Comment: Es una libreria que importe, compile 'com.github.tibolte:agendacalendarview:1.0.4'

Comment: Puedes agregar como obtienes titulo y fecha por favor, veo que CalendarEvent es una interfaz.

Comment: Lo obtengo a travez del metodo,
 `public void onEventSelected(CalendarEvent calendarEvent)`
y calendarEvent devuelte una cadena con el titulo y la fecha. pero eso ya esta especificado en la clase BaseCalendarEvent que esta dentro de la libreria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes obtener de esta forma dentro de método `onEventSelected()` :

```
@Override
    public void onEventSelected(CalendarEvent calendarEvent) {
     Log.d("MainActivity", "id del evento: " + calendarEvent.getId());
    }
```

de hecho dentro de ese mismo método se puede obtener como comentas, el titulo y el día.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero que ciego, muchas gracias @Elenasys.

Comment: no te preocupes, de hecho dentro del método escribe  calendarEvent y cuando agregues el punto puedes ver los valores que puedes obtener de CalendarEvent, saludos!

Comment: si ya logre hacerlo, gracias!